# Incorrect characters in output

Tags: xpath, utf-8, web-scraping, domdocument

I'm trying to learn web scraping with Xpath. The code below works, however the output contains of incorrect characters and I can't manage to get this right.

Example:

- Output: EmÃƒÂ¥mejeriet
- How it should be:  Emåmejeriet

PHP Code:

```
<?php
// Tried with these parameters but they doesn't make any difference
$html = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$html->loadHtmlFile('http://thesite.com/thedoc.html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
$nodelist = $xpath->query("//table");
foreach ($nodelist as $n) {
    echo $n->nodeValue."\n";
}
?>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) & [decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) `php` functions if using ISO8859-15 or [iconv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) if not.

Example :

```
<?php
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
iconv_set_encoding("output_encoding", "ISO-8859-1");
?>
```